# Viewing requirements for Arrow S04E08 and The Flash S02E08

Tags: dc, suggested-order, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

From the brief episode descriptions I've read for The Flash S02E08 (Legends of Today) and Arrow S04E08 (Legends of Yesterday), they appear to be two parts of the same story. I've watched all episodes of Arrow up to S04E07, but never watched any episodes of The Flash. I don't currently have time to catch up on about one and a third seasons of a show with ~40 minute episodes. With that in mind, I'm looking for some guidance on how to approach watching these episodes.

Can I just skip the The Flash S02E08 and just watch Arrow S04E08? Will I be missing crucial information from the first part that's required for the second to make sense?

If I do need (or choose) to watch The Flash S02E08 first, are there any episodes of The Flash I'll need to have watched first for it to make sense?

If I skip both of them, am I missing anything in Arrow S04E08 which relates to the ongoing season four storyline?

Comment: Since this was just bumped and it wasn't point out below, I'll just mention it here:  These two episodes form some of the backstory for the spinoff _[Legends of Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_Tomorrow)_.  And since I am posting from the future - there's further crossovers with _Legends of Tomorrow_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to watch Flash S02 E08 first in order to understand Arrow S04 E08. It is a continuous story, with the break between episodes similar to a commercial break.

If you have not watched flash or Arrow it might be helpful but not necessary to the story.

If you want to skip this episode of Arrow and continue with Arrow S04 E09 you will actually miss some important topics that should be further plot-lines in Arrow continuing from her on out.

The same is true if you want to skip S02 E08 of the flash, you will miss important Flash future plot points.

HOWEVER, if you watch just the Flash, or Arrow episodes, despite being confused on the plots, you will at least get your own individual show's continuing plot points.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll be watching my first episode of The Flash then. Thanks!